# How to create php file using php

Tags: php, heredoc

I'm trying to create multiple .php files using php itself.
I want to put some code into a file; most of code is the same but only one or two variables that I wanted to be dynamic. I mean every file that I make are exactly like each other the only difference between theme is one variable.
My function is [this](http://pastebin.ca/3208458):

```
function generate_corn_files()
{
        $C = $GLOBALS['C'];
        $db = $GLOBALS['db'];

        //delete all contents of folder
        RemoveDir($C->INCPATH.'cron/feed/', false);
        $res    = $db->query('SELECT id FROM category ');
        while($cat = $db->fetch_object($res)) {
                $id     = $cat->id;

                $open_output = <<<'PHP'
<?php
$outter_id      = $id;
if($example = true){
        echo 'test';
        echo $C->INCPATH;
}

?>
PHP;
                $fp=fopen($C->INCPATH.'cron/feed/filename_'.$id.'.php','w');
                fwrite($fp, $open_output);
                fclose($fp);
        }
}
```

I tried to put content of file using heredoc but I want to `$id` in `$outter_id      = $id;` be equal to `$id     = $cat->id;`
it's a variable outside of `heredoc` I can't make it work inside of it !
Are there any other solutions to make it work ?

Comment: nobody here to help !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using [HEREDOC syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) but rather [NOWDOC syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc). If you use HEREDOC, all variables inside will be evaluated, so you will have to escape with `\$` the variables you don't want evaluated.

```
$open_output = <<<PHP
<?php
\$outter_id      = $id;
if(\$example = true){
        echo 'test';
        echo \$C->INCPATH;
}
?>
PHP;
```

Or, you can stick with NOWDOC, use a placeholder, and replace it afterwards.

```
$open_output = <<<'PHP'
<?php
$outter_id      = %%%id%%%;
if($example = true){
        echo 'test';
        echo $C->INCPATH;
}
?>
PHP;
str_replace("%%%id%%%", $id, $open_output);
```

Comment: thank you , best answer , placeholder did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could inspire you

```
function generate_corn_files()
{
    $C = $GLOBALS['C'];
    $db = $GLOBALS['db'];

    //delete all contents of folder
    RemoveDir($C->INCPATH.'cron/feed/', false);
    $res    = $db->query('SELECT id FROM category ');
    while($cat = $db->fetch_object($res)) {
            $id     = $cat->id;

            $open_output = <<<'PHP'
<?php
$outter_id      = $id;
if($example = true){
    echo 'test';
    echo $C->INCPATH;
}

?>
PHP;

    $php_var_name_pattern = '/\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/';
    $open_output = preg_replace_callback(
        $php_var_name_pattern, 
        function($matches) {
                if(isset($GLOBALS[$matches[1]])) {
                        if(is_string($GLOBALS[$matches[1]])) { 
                                return '\''.$GLOBALS[$matches[1]].'\'';
                        } else {
                                return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]];
                        }
                } else { 
                        return $matches[0];
                }          
        }, 
        $open_output);

        $fp=fopen($C->INCPATH.'cron/feed/filename_'.$id.'.php','w');
            fwrite($fp, $open_output);
            fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! good answer , but i was wondering isn't there any way to create .php file and fill it with php codes instead of using <<<heredoc ?

Comment: No easy way that won't be a formatting and debugging nightmare as what you are doing is somewhat unusual, this is the best way IMHO.

Comment: Actually you are not using heredoc-syntax, but newdoc-syntax which is equivalent, in some close way, to single-quoted strings, thus why don't you use old-single-quoted strings?